# TURN Coturn Server Azure VM deployed

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I would like to know, if anyone has expirience in deploying an coturn STUN/TURN Server on a Azure VM. I have tried and and failed several times to get the TURN Server work. I have followed these steps carefully https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2018/01/29/orchestrating-turn-servers-cloud-deployment/ but it didn't work out.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need open port 3478 on Azure NSG.